# Adventure Works for SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql-server, adventureworks

I was tasked to find the names of Employees that have worked in 2 departments, I feel like my formatting is incorrect as it is only appearing with 1 result where it is meant to come back with 4, If anyone could look over it and let me know if I have some syntax error that would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT P.FirstName,LastName, COUNT(D.DepartmentID) as Departments
FROM HumanResources.EmployeeDepartmentHistory D
INNER JOIN Person.Person P ON P.BusinessEntityID = D.DepartmentID 
GROUP BY P.FirstName,LastName
HAVING COUNT(DepartmentID)=2
```

Comment: when you say "employees that have worked in two departments", it can be any of two departments which means **one employee can work in one or more departments**. is it correct? if it is possible can you provide the table structure here?

Comment: Please provide sample data and table structures

Answer (score 1):

`ON P.BusinessEntityID = D.DepartmentID` - is not going to give a sensible result 
try `ON P.BusinessEntityID = D.BusinessEntityID`